# Regex: difference between ^a and a.*

Tags: regex

I have been looking everywhere and I just cannot find anybody looking for the answer.
what is the difference between:

```
'/^a/'
```

and

```
'/a.*/'
```

both of them say: give me everything that starts with 'a'.
so what is the difference?

edit: I am not adding the regex tool since i was not trying it out on a specific one.

Comment: The slhshes are not part of the actual regular expression. Whether `a` means "`a` at beginning of line" or "`a` anywhere on a line" depends on the regex dialect and the host language. Like the [tag:regex] tag guidance already told you when you selected it, you need to specify which regex tool or dialect you are asking about.

Comment: "I am not adding the regex tool since i was not trying it out on a specific one." Yes, you were. Regexes are not universal across all tools. Python is not the same as Google Analytics is not the same as Notepad++ is not the same as grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^a/` means "match the beginning of the string, and then the character `a`".

`/a.*/` means "match the character `a` anywhere in the string, and then 0 or more of any other characters."

`/^a/` and `/a.*/` both match "apple" but only `/a.*/` will match "cat".

Comment: Whether `/a…/` means "anywhere in the string" or not depends also on how the regex is applied on the string

Answer (score 0):

`/^a/` matches `"a"` at the beginning of a string, but `/a.*/` matches`"a"` and all following characters.

That means that `/^a/` in `"abc"` matches only `"a"`, but `/a.*/` in the same string matches `"abc"`. Hope it helped!

Comment: It's weird to say "marks" when you mean "matches". This seems to pretty much duplicate the earlier answer.